# PHP Compressing png image on the fly

Tags: php, image, compression, png, photo

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

Here is my simple code :

```
$img=imagecreate(300,300);

$black=imagecolorallocate($img,0,0,0);
$white=imagecolorallocate($img,255,255,255);

imagefill($img,0,0,$white);
imagerectangle($img,10,10,289,289,$black);

header ('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
```

Now... If you save the exported file and upload it to yahoo smushit

```
http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/
```

You may notice that it can be compressed even more.

My goal is to export a compressed png image directly from php (on the fly) and that it would be fully optimized (compressed).

I have notice that `imagepng` have a compression parameter 0-9 but for some reason it is not working for me...

Comment: PNGs are *always* compressed, it's part of their specification. But there are different ways of compression (the old speed vs. size tradeoff). To get a "fully compressed" PNG, a utility such as `pngcrush` tries *all* permutations. It takes a while, since there are a lot.

Comment: Great ! Where can I get that php function as php code and merge it to my code ?

Comment: You simply don't want to spent so much time compressing an image if you are returning it to a web request. Forget about it.